# C++: How to access a member variable whose name is stored in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

Suppose I have a string array like this:

```
string registers[2] = {"r0","r1"}
```

And a struct like this:

```
struct cpu {
    int r1;
}
```

I tried something like this:

```
cpu *p = (cpu*)malloc(sizeof(cpu));
cout << p->registers[1] << endl;
```

But this gave a compilation error. How to implement this?

EDIT: Problem description

I need to access the member of a cpu class using an index so I thought I could just put the names of the memebers in an array and then get the name of the member using the index

Comment: Instead of `int r1;` you could have `int r[2];` which might make things easier to have an array of registers.

Comment: If you absolutely need to access members by string names at runtime, consider using a `std::(unordered_)map` containing member-pointers as the mapped element type.

Comment: It might be better to describe your functional requirements than to coarsely sketch your approach. Your design has so many flaws, it is difficult to guess what the [real problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) is.

Comment: @JaMiT I need to access the member of a cpu class using an index so I thought I could just put the names of the memebers in an array and then get the name of the member using the index

Comment: @LipunPanda But your `cpu` class has only one member... how hard is it to decide which one member to access when there is only one member? Perhaps you over-simplified your example?

Comment: @JaMiT yes the example is simplified. In the actual class there are 33 members

Comment: @LipunPanda why are you using malloc if the question is tagged C++?

Comment: Here is something I whipped up https://onlinegdb.com/yXmtgJN4E based on the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415283/stdmap-of-polymorphic-member-variables-pointers  It uses a map of string to member pointers so the registers are still stored in an external struct and not in the map.

Comment: @LipunPanda I wrote "over-simplified" not merely "simplified". You've removed so many details that your issue has become trivial. At the very least, your example `cpu` structure should have two fields (`r0` and `r1`) to match the two entries in your example `registers` array. In addition, you should expand upon why you are using strings in your array; in particular, is that data type open to change? (In the absence of other factors, I'd lean toward using pointers-to-member instead of concocting a string-to-member transformation.) In summary: *what are your functional requirements?*

Answer (score 8):

Your code is completely illformed. Expression `p->registers` uses default operator `->`  which requires left-hand operator to be a pointer to a type which would have a member with name used as right-hand operator (`registers`). Your `cpu` doesn't contain `registers`.

Steps to emulate behaviour like one you desire for whatever reason that is:

1. design a way to associate particular `string` to a member of `cpu`, by index or pointer to member.
2. map the string value to an index or a pointer to member.
3. C++ allows to encapsulate that using member operators,which would result in something like `p["r0"]` yielding a reference to `r0`.

In simplest case, when all elements are of same type, you may just use a `std::map` or a class designed similarly, e.g.

```
struct cpu {
    std::map<std::string, int> registers;

    // constructor initializes the map
    cpu() : registers ( { {"r0", 0}, 
                          {"r1", 0} 
                        }) 
    {}
};
```

Here an expression `p->registers["r0"]` would give you  reference to  value associated with "r0" key, etc.

***NB*** The creation of cpu object should be

```
cpu *p = new cpu();
```

Comment: @LipunPanda here you are, but honestly, be considerate with what you do, I have no comprehension of real task to offer proper solution and you apparently struggle with basics. THis example got own costs

Comment: [Jerry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67565176/1312382) appears superior to me: only one global map, only filled once, not with every instance, and most of all, not modifying the `cpu` struct structurally, which is of special relevance if the class should be mapped to some specific memory, e. g. (`auto cpu0 = new(SpecificCPU0Address) cpu();` (no further CPU registers overwritten by map access in this case).

Comment: @aconcagua I concur, though that works only in case if there is only single kind of `cpu`. If memory mapping is true we actually are creating an adapter in that case.

Comment: Ah, my fault... [Duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67565067/c-best-way-to-access-class-members-using-index?noredirect=1&lq=1) hints more clearly into that direction, missed that this question is (appears, at least) more generic...

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example that uses a mapping of string to cpu member:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct cpu {
    int r0;
    int r1;
};

map<string,int cpu::*> registers = {
    {"r0",&cpu::r0},
    {"r1",&cpu::r1}
};

int main()
{
    cpu x{0, 1};
    cout << " x.r1 = " << x.r1 << ",  x.*registers[\"r1\"] = " << x.*registers["r1"] << "\n";
    x.*registers["r1"] = 2;
    cout << " x.r1 = " << x.r1 << ",  x.*registers[\"r1\"] = " << x.*registers["r1"] << "\n";
    
    cpu *p = &x;
    p->*registers["r1"] = 3;
    cout << "p->r1 = " << p->r1 << ", p->*registers[\"r1\"] = " << p->*registers["r1"] << "\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/d2KqBH0Mo

And here is one that, like your original example, uses an integer index into an array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct cpu {
    int r0;
    int r1;
};

int cpu::* registers[] = {
    &cpu::r0,
    &cpu::r1
};

int main()
{
    cpu x{0, 1};
    cout << " x.r1 = " << x.r1 << ",  x.*registers[1] = " << x.*registers[1] << "\n";
    x.*registers[1] = 2;
    cout << " x.r1 = " << x.r1 << ",  x.*registers[1] = " << x.*registers[1] << "\n";
    
    cpu *p = &x;
    p->*registers[1] = 3;
    cout << "p->r1 = " << p->r1 << ", p->*registers[1] = " << p->*registers[1] << "\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/3hWpmEijs