# C++: Best way to access class members using index

Tags: c++

I have a class like this:

```
class cpu
{
    int r0;
    int r1;
    int r2;
    ......
    ......
    int r31;
}
```

Now there is a function like this which sets the value of the register:

```
void setVal(string regName, int val)
{
    //Here I want to do something like this
    this->regName = val;
}
```

The registers are private members so can't be accessed outside. Since there are 32 members, using `switch` isn't really efficient.

Comment: You could use an array `int r[32];` instead of 32 variables. Doesn't really solve your problem but could make many things easier. However, could you please clarify what `regName` would be? Maybe you could parse it as int and use an array, maybe not.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that with strings. I assume `regName` represents your member names `r0`, `r1`, ... If you - for some reasons - can't use an array and do normal indexing, there is a way to do pointer hackery, but that's technically UB and you still need an index number, not a string. If you really want to use a string, you either have to parse it somehow to a number or use a lookup table.

Comment: I just answered an almost identical question by you at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67563502/c-how-to-access-a-member-variable-whose-name-is-stored-in-an-array/67565176#67565176   Is this the duplicate or is the other one the duplicate?

Comment: Using a string for this purpose isn't really best choice anyway – if at all, the function should accept it as reference to const: `std::string const& regname`. Integral constants are much better suited for; if you still need better names than just integral constants you might define an `enum` or `enum class`.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Good you mention this, was about to write the same answer :D I'd say the other is the dupe, because the other one has answers.

Comment: before you search a technical solution, you should think about your design. If you really need addressing data via strings, you can use  associative containers e.g. std::map. But all this comes with a huge overhead. Especially because std::map is designed for dynamic add/remove, it offers a lot of unneeded functionality and is very inefficient in your use case. `switch` can't be used to compare against `string`, so you need a much more inefficient string compare function. You really need it?

Comment: @churil i can use integers instead of regName

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the signature of the class member ( variable and `setVal` function) ( or for better say you want to maintain this interface ), the best solution is the following:

Declare a map in the class

```
#include <map>
class cpu
{
    int r0;
    int r1;
    int r2;
    ......
    ......
    int r31;

    std::map<std::string, int*> regNameToVariable;
}
```

In the constructor initiliaze it in this way:

```
cpu::cpu(){
    regNameToVariable["r0"] = &r0;
    regNameToVariable["r1"] = &r1;
    ......
    ......
    regNameToVariable["r31"] = &r31;
}
```

Then the `setVal` function look like this:

```
void setVal(string regName, int val)
{   
    if(this->regNameToVariable.find(regName) != this->regNameToVariable.end()){ //check if register exist in map
         this->regNameToVariable.at(regName) = val;
    }
}
```

Obviously the best way to do this operation remains the array, and the index of the array as index of register. But if you can't change the interface you write in the question, the above is the best and smart solution.

Comment: Maybe even better if the map was static and contained class member pointers? One would have to fill it only once at programme startup and the `cpu` struct would not have to be modified either.